# mysqli php query doesnt insert character "+"

Tags: php, character-encoding, mysqli

I'm using php and mysqli and I meet a problem with an insert query which looks like :

```
    SET NAMES 'utf8'
    $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $text)
    insert into table values('', '".$text."');
```

Pages are encoded utf8 without BOM and mysql is utf8 general ci

The problem is when I use phpmyadmin the request works fine but when I use website interface and type a text with character "+" it replace with a space " " in mysql but all other characters like ', ", accents, \, /, % are correctly inserted...
It worked before I probably made a mistake.

Thanks you by advance and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Have you tried binded parameters with prepared statements?

Comment: Hello I'm not good with prepared queries and I know I will have to use them, but I don't understand the problem here and it makes me crazy :)

Comment: So ! I've tried prepared query for that and the text I've added is still without "+"... Oh despair...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is neither mysql, not mysqli, not PHP.
None of them put any special meaning in this character.

If you care to verify your inserts, by simply echoing `$text` out before insert, you will see that it is already stripped of + sign. So, you have to find the code that strips that symbol out.

A program is not a "black box" which you feed with data and it returns some unexpected output.
But rather *set of operators*, each performing some data manipulations.

So, you have to *debug* your code, means you have to echo your $text variable out in various parts of your code to see where it gets changed. Most likely it is getting some unnecessary treatment. After finding that code you may either remove it or ask here if it ok or not.

The only possible case of automated replacement of + character would be if you type your text right in the browser's address bar. In this case + can be replaced with space automatically as PHP does decode urlencoded text and + is used to substitute space character in the URL

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I'm new to coding and it seems you showing me the way because this adding is ajax sent to php file so I'm on it and will come back for news. thanks again.

Comment: Well you were right because of ajax bad use of "encodeURI" function, In fact "encodeURIComponent" is needed when the value sent is not like URL already existing and is composed by characters you need to display like comments or text composed by user. So great thanks for showing me the way and apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: I was wrong for tags if a moderator could change them into characters encoding and javascript it would be great thanks for great website and community.